# Handling "large data json requests" with multiple ajax requests

Tags: jquery, json

What is the best way to handle large data
PHP Array past though multiple ajax requests.

For example.
I have a php array which contains 10,000 product id's which is the result of the first ajax request
Once on the second ajax request, I have to first query again to get the 10,000 product id's then in addition the 2nd request may fetch a further 3000 product id's

So the process is: 
in each request we need to modify the product ids append/remove.

The method I am currently looking into is storing the id's via session or cookie.
But the best solution would be to serialize the array then past through jsonEncode

The problem is this must be to much data to be pass through each request.
I have currently tried setting a global at the top of our script.

var globalProductIds = 0

then on success of each request we would override the product id's and send with the next request.
globalProductIds = data.productIds;

Currently this freezes the browser.
The only other method which I can think of if json is not going to work, would be to store the id's in the database, this is not particularly a good solution as there could be 1000's of rows generated for each user per minute.

Hopefully someone out there has a better suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems I have got no response in the past 24hrs.
After further research it seems javascript is not the best method for processing large amounts of data.

I have now started to build a caching system which uses the database.
This certainly seems to be the best solution now.